# Transforming a list of nodes in to a nested dict in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, tree, adjacency-list

I have a list of dicts in python that represents an adjacency list and i want to transform this list in to a nested python dict. with `name` and `children` keys.

#### List of nodes

This is an example of the list of dicts, those are the 10 first elements of the list. The original contains 1000 elements.

```py
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'External sector', 'parent_id': 0},
 {'id': 3, 'name': 'Capital and financial markets', 'parent_id': 0},
 {'id': 77, 'name': 'Credit indicators', 'parent_id': 0},
 {'id': 15, 'name': 'Economic activity', 'parent_id': 0},
 {'id': 17, 'name': 'Monetary indicators', 'parent_id': 0},
 {'id': 30, 'name': 'Regional economy', 'parent_id': 0},
 {'id': 114, 'name': 'International economy', 'parent_id': 0},
 {'id': 157, 'name': 'National private financial system', 'parent_id': 0},
 {'id': 176, 'name': 'Financial Stability', 'parent_id': 0},
 {'id': 222, 'name': 'Financial Inclusion', 'parent_id': 0}]
```

### What i've tried

I've found this function in SO that is able to transform this list of dicts in to a nested python dict:

```py
def list_to_tree(data):
    out = { 
#         0: { 'id': 0, 'parent_id': 0, 'name': "Root node", 'sub': [] }
    }

    for p in data:
        out.setdefault(p['parent_id'], { 'sub': [] })
        out.setdefault(p['id'], { 'sub': [] })
        out[p['id']].update(p)
        out[p['parent_id']]['sub'].append(out[p['id']])

    return out[0]
```

This function produces dicts in this way:

```py
{'id': 0,
 'name': 'rootnode',
 'parent_id': None,
 'sub': [{'id': 1,
          'name': 'External sector',
          'parent_id': 0,
          'sub': [{'id': 2,
                   'name': 'Exchange rates',
                   'parent_id': 1,
                   'sub': [{'id': 242,
                            'name': 'Controlled or free rates',
                            'parent_id': 2,
                            'sub': []},
                           {'id': 243,
                            'name': 'Floating rates',
                            'parent_id': 2,
                            'sub': []},
                           {'id': 532,
                            'name': 'Real and effective exchange rate indices',
                            'parent_id': 2,
                            'sub': []},
                           {'id': 533,
                            'name': 'Foreign exchange and wage indicators',
                            'parent_id': 2,
                            'sub': []},
                           {'id': 548,
                            'name': 'Average of period',
                            'parent_id': 2,
                            'sub': []},
```

But i wanted to produce dicts in this way, without the id's

```py
{
 'name': 'rootnode',
 'children': [{
          'name': 'External sector',
          'children': [{
                   'name': 'Exchange rates',
                   'children': [{
                            'name': 'Controlled or free rates',
                            'children': []},
                           {
                            'name': 'Floating rates',
                            'children': []},
                           {
                            'name': 'Real and effective exchange rate indices',
                            'children': []},
                           {
                            'name': 'Foreign exchange and wage indicators',
                            'children': []},
                           {
                            'name': 'Average of period',
                            'children': []},
```

Is there any way that i can change this function that i've found in order to produce the desired output?
Any hint, tip or advice is more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function with slight modifications:

- Use the 'children' key instead of 'sub'
- Initialise the root node with only the keys you want to have (name & children)
- Instead of calling `.update` (which copies *all* keys), assign just the 'name' key

```
def list_to_tree(data):
    out = { 
        0: { 'name': 'rootnode', 'children': [] }
    }

    for p in data:
        out.setdefault(p['parent_id'], { 'children': [] })
        out.setdefault(p['id'], { 'children': [] })
        out[p['id']]['name'] = p['name']
        out[p['parent_id']]['children'].append(out[p['id']])

    return out[0]
```

Comment: you saved me , don't know how to thank you

Comment: Always nice to read that an answer was useful!

Answer (score 0):

transform list of dict (adjacency id-parent and other keys) to nested dict (id, children[], other keys...

```
def nested_tree(data, id='id', parent='parent', children='children', 
root=None, delete_parent=True):
    nodes = list(filter(lambda item: item[parent] == root, data))
    def get_children(node):
        nested = []
        for item in list(filter(lambda item: item[parent] == node[id], data)):
            item[children] = get_children(item)
            if delete_parent:
                nested.append((lambda parent, **kw: kw)(**item))
            else:
                nested.append(item)
        return nested

    for node in nodes:
        node[children] = get_children(node)
        if delete_parent:
            del node[parent]
    return nodes
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).